# Ansible: Can we have custom names for host_vars files

Tags: variables, ansible, ansible-inventory, inventory

**What is working**

I have ansible inventory organized as below:

```
../project1
  |- group_vars
  |- host_vars
    |- 10.20.30.1.yml
       {{content like remote-endpoint="x.x.x.x", ... a very big var map... ,}}
    |- 10.20.30.2.yml
       {{content like remote-endpoint="y.y.y.y", ... a very big var map... ,}}
  inventory
```

content of my inventory file is as below:

```
10.20.30.1  hvar="host1"
10.20.30.2  hvar="host2"
```

The above works as expected, I am able to access all the host-level variables for the specific hosts.

**What I wanted to do?**

I wanted to have names of the host_vars/*files* to be based on the tags (maybe) like - *host1, host2, etc* instead of the value of "inventory_hostsname" ansible variable. This will enable me to give some function-specific names like *master, slave, etc* also in the latter case, the names of the files can remain the same even if the host changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible gives the option to give name like you want. Actually that is the preferred way as well. You can define all your hosts in ansible `hosts`(not /etc/hosts) file like this.

```
allgrouphost1
allrouphost2

[master]
host1

[slave]
host2
host3
host4
```

You can then define the variables in `host_vars/host1.yml`, `host_vars/host2.yml` and so on.

You can define hosts ip address in `hosts` file or their specific host vars file with `ansible_host` variable.

With `hosts` file

```
host1 ansible_host=192.0.2.98 ansible_user=deploy
```

wih `host_vars/host1.yml` file

```
ansible_host: 192.0.2.98
ansible_user: deploy
```

The headings in brackets are group names(`[master]`, `[slave]`), which are used in classifying hosts and deciding what hosts you are controlling at what times and for what purpose.

You can run playbooks by group name so that, those are executed only on those hosts that belongs to that group. You can also define common variables in `group_vars` file.

See the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) for more details and use case.